# What is this question trying to ask?

Tags: logic-gates

I'm not an electronics students, I was doing erasmus for my chance I got electronics education, I have a project to complete I've made 9 of 10 exercises but I'm unable to understand what this question asking me to do:

"Design a natural binary code code transcode (3bits) for the code +3 (excess3) (4bits). In the selected simulator (best is falstad) perform a working system."

Can someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: you should form your question much more clearly.

Comment: @mehmet.ali.anil It would be better if you suggest specific improvements that the OP could make. We also try to show a good example with our comments, by capitalizing appropriately for example.

Answer (score -1):

Search and understand:

- "natural binary code 3-bit"
- "excess-3 code"

My guess for the rest is that it means:

- create a design that represents it
- translate the design into RTL
- simulate the RTL

Comment: Also:  "Falstad circuit simulator applet